# queue async functions inside loop to execute in order without callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, svg

I know there are some other posts here with similar questions, but none help me...

I need to execute some functions in order (they are async) to animate svg elements, one after the previous ends, but inside a loop. This is my code:

```
    function begin (i,time){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.pie-chart animate')[i].beginElement();
        },time);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<$('.pie-chart animate').length;i++){
        dur = $('.pie-chart animate').eq(i).attr('dur');
        time = parseInt(dur.substr(0,1));
        time = time * 1000;
        begin(i,time);
    }
```

After this, all animations execute at the same time. Can anyone help me?, thanks ^^.

Comment: You should use something like success callbacks that check to see whether certain SVG elements have been fully rendered.

Comment: There is absolutely no [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) in your code?

Comment: they are async but I don't see any ajax in code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'By in order, I think you mean synchronous, and by (not AJAX) I think you mean not asynchronously.  To do this properly (async), you should use callbacks.  Something like this:

```
function begin (i){
    if (i >= $('.pie-chart animate').length) return;//you're done
    dur = $('.pie-chart animate').eq(i).attr('dur');
    time = parseInt(dur.substr(0,1));
    time = time * 1000;

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.pie-chart animate')[i].beginElement();
        begin(i+1);    
    },time);
}

 begin(0);
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that jQuery keeps evaluating the same expression inside the loop whereas it would be better to cache the results somewhere and iterate over that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your time is been reset in the loop, so if you have dur *9s* in all your animations, all will start after 9 seconds.

In the loop, you need to execute the begin with sum of duration from all iterated elements before the current. Look example:

```
function begin (i,time){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.pie-chart animate')[i].beginElement();
    },time);
}

var time = 0;
for(var i=0;i<$('.pie-chart animate').length;i++){
    dur = $('.pie-chart animate').eq(i).attr('dur');
    time += parseInt(dur, 10) * 1000;
    begin(i, (i===0)?0:time);
}
```